# Add (N) to duplicated file name in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, file, filenames

I was wondering if there is an algorithm way to add numbers in duplicated filename. As example I have following example simple documents in a `file` collection:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788f6"
        "name": "sample.txt",
    },    
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788f7"
        "name": "sample(2).txt",
    },    
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788f8"
        "name": "sample(4).txt",
    },    
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788f9"
        "name": "sample(5).txt",
    },
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788fa"
        "name": "other-sample.txt",
    },
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788fb"
        "name": "sample",
    },
    {
        "_id": "612ead8668bfcc4221a788fc"
        "name": "sample.txt.gz",
    }
]
```

Now I want to add new document called:

```json
{"name": "sample.txt"}
```

Is there an algorithm where I can automatically change it to either `sample(3).txt` (because there is no sample(3).txt in collection) or `sample(6).txt` (skip all previously number)?

My original idea was to use `.count()` with the filter of checking "sample(N).txt" (per regex). But that would be not accurate because as example of documents, there exists "sample(N).txt" 4 times. Calling "sample(4).txt" is not correct because it already exists there.

Maybe there is a way with regex to find highest file name count and pull it from here? Documents can have additional field name if it needs to be. (Or maybe adding a `duplicated` number field can be useful here and then with `$max` in `.aggregate()` you can get the highest duplicated file name? Is that efficient?)

Additional Notes:

- `sample.txt-note` or `sample.txt.gz` is unique and shouldn't act as duplicated file name from `sample.txt`
- file name without extension should work as well (`sample`, `sample(1)`, `sample(2)` etc.)
- Fastest algorithm as possible / least write or/and read call. Using for-loop for every duplicated file name would be too slow / costly (Planned to use MongoDB Atlas Serverless)

I'm using:

- nodejs (TypeScript/JavaScript) with native mongodb driver (not mongoose)
- MongoDB 5.0

If someone has an idea - that would be amazing! Thank you! <3

P.S. if I happen to have a solution for this, then of course I'll post it here too for future visitors! :)

P.S.(2) I'm totally fine if examples are in different programming language!

Comment: maybe having a second collection to have that counter would be easier, for example 
`{"filename" : "sample" "availiable" : [3 6]}` to mean that those are the not-taken numbers. And everytime you need a number, you can do FindAndModify to get the number that is free based on the name.

Comment: Are you okay with running a `find()` operation and getting all files named `sample(n)`?

Comment: @Takis_ that's a very interesting idea and may be very efficient! I'll see what I can play around here!

Comment: @programmerRaj Only drawback is if you happend to have tons of documents/files called this sample(n) - that can be slow? But I'm fine either. Any ideas are welcome + I'm thankfully :)

Comment: What if you used a hash of the file to uniquely identify then instead of keeping the filename unique? This isn't really answering the question, it would be an alternative.

Comment: @programmerRaj Problem with that is if you want to sync the files on actual OS (Linux, Windows, macOS) it won't work because those OS doesn't allow you to have same file name on same folder. This is also a known issue at Google Drive (One Drive don't allow you to use same file name). Hence the file name should be unique, at least on same folder.

Answer (score 0):

use the KISS model, and don't make it complicated...run a counter, that increments on every addition.  Just append this to every file.  If you don't care about the number added, then each file can be unique if you just add a number (or whatever marker that can be unique... "xxx12345xxx" as an example marker)

and live to code another day. :)

Comment: But what if someone decide to add, let say, 3 sample.txt. Now we have sample.txt, sample(1).txt and sample(2).txt.

And then I change the sample(1).txt to sample(3).txt for yolo and I add a new "sample.txt" again. There would be conflict because sample(3).txt already exists?

Thank you so much for the reply! :)

Comment: I'm suggesting, if you can, make a unique marker, that your filenames won't have.  Something like "XXX" concatenated with "number counter variable", concatenated with "XXX".  The result is "xxx12345xxx".  if you have certainty about filenames, you can just append this marker to all files, and you'll have unique filenames.  You can add an error check to test if there is already the filename existing for this newly created file  name just to make sure.  if so, then increment and recheck!

Comment: thus, sample(1).txt becomes sample(1)_xxx12345xxx.txt, and sample(2).txt becomes sample(2)_xxx12346xxx.txt and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Original author here - currently I solved a different way for duplicated file:

instead calling

```
sample.txt
sample(1).txt
sample(2).txt
```

I decided doing this:

```
sample.txt
sample.txt (duplicated-6rdcfXNdY2FZpuF)
sample.txt (duplicated-Qkc8eEeBV4Scr87)
```

This way it's more efficient and good enough for me. Alternative would be using random id + dates to identify which duplicated file name is newer.

I won't mark this as "correct answer" because it's not really solution to the questions (yet).

Comment: I can understand that this solves your problem but why do you call the (1) and (2) are "duplicated"? If you check this behavior on a filesystem the numbering still make sure that the system has a UNIQUE filename.  So for me - as also similar posted in second answer - just use the name as the name and the documentId as the unique value. To make sure that the content is a duplicated content you may add something like a checksum (SHA) to identify new and old content of the documents.

Comment: @TomFreudenberg - yep, you're actually right, "duplicated" make no sense for wording here. Duplicated was meant for file name, not the file content itself.

Problem with that is if you want to sync the files on actual OS (Linux, Windows, macOS) it won't work because those OS doesn't allow you to have same file name on same folder. This is also a known issue at Google Drive (One Drive don't allow you to use same file name). Hence the file name should be unique on same folder.